# Проблема с установкой selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Добрый вечер, сообщество.

Прошу помощи с такой проблемой: не могу установить selenium для использования в питоне.

Поставил pip, пробую `pip install -U selenium`.

Вроде бы пакет такой найден, но возникает UnicodeDecodeError (не такая уж для питона и редкость).

Гуглил усердно, но пока решения проблемы не нашел.

Comment: Точно не помню, но вроде как такая ошибка возникала, когда имя пользователя было написано на русском языке. Лечилось правкой исходников - указывал вручную каталог, в который надо было копировать. Посмотрите, может быть, у вас та же проблема.

UPD: в файле Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pip\locations.py в функции __get_username вместо `return getpass.getuser()` сделал просто `return 'Andrey'`, и проблема ушла, но повторюсь: не уверен, что была именно ваша ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за совет.
Проблему эту так и не решил, но добился желаемого с помощью easy_install

Comment: В таких случаях полный traceback может помочь диагностировать проблему.

Comment: @Archie, вам уже кто-нибудь советовал использовать для программирования на python какой-нибудь дистрибутив linux, а не windows?

Comment: @Montreal, Советовали, и этим советам я следую) Но сейчас понадобилось срочно и на чужой машине.